# Way to extract mp3 sample in .NET and C#

Tags: c#, .net, mp3

How can I extract some MP3 sample from an MP3 file? 
I want to extract some sample of about 10 seconds from these files.

Is there any way or some documentation that I can study in order to do that by myself?
Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a [C# wrapper](https://jasonjano.wordpress.com/2010/02/09/a-simple-c-wrapper-for-ffmpeg/) around ffmpeg, to convert the file to wav. 
From there, you can extract whatever sample you want.

WAV-file documentation:
http://www-mmsp.ece.mcgill.ca/Documents/AudioFormats/WAVE/WAVE.html

Comment: Like you said I used ffmpeg, but in the C# wrapper I added the commands to do that. In fact it is possible to cut audio files in ffmpeg directly with a command line like 
`ffmpeg.exe -ss position -t duration -i inputFile.mp3 outputfile.mp3`. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Leo: Interesting, didn't know that ;) Glad I could help.